# webapp2 routes for locale in URL

Tags: google-app-engine, internationalization, locale, webapp2

The webapp2 i18n documentation has an example of specifying the locale in a parameter, e.g.:

```
www.example.com?locale=en_US
```

but Google search console says that this is [not recommended](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192).

I'd like to instead put the locale in the URL like this:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/about
www.example.com/contact
www.example.com/fr
www.example.com/fr/about
www.example.com/fr/contact
```

What is a good way of setting up your webapp2 routes and passing the locale as a parameter to your handlers?

Comment: FWIW - the 'Not recommended' in that link *might* be a mistake - it's on the `Pros` column (and also lacks explanation). I'd probably ignore it if I otherwise liked the idea.

Comment: @DanCornilescu, I've seen the same advice elsewhere so I don't think it is a mistake.  I'm tempted to do it anyway because it is such an easy solution, but on the other hand it would be painful to change the implementation later if I needed to...

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. An explanation would help w/ the decision. Was there one in the other place?

Comment: @DanCornilescu, yes, though I didn't fully understand.  It relates to Google indexing being able to understand that you have a multi-lingual site and being able to track traffic to the different language versions of your site with analytics tools.  Given the importance of Google search results, I want to follow their best practices!

Comment: Ah, I see now. Yep, it could be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try the way I do it: Set a regex (`app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)', RegionSearch)], config=settings.w2config, debug=settings.DEBUG)` and then "pass on" the parameter to the template where you can set the locate arbitrarily for many different locales, timezones and currencies e.g.

```
   {% if request.... == "..." %} # depend on values in the request
        {% set currency = "SEK" %}
        {% set format = "sv_SE" %}
        {% set timezoneinfo = 'Europe/Stockholm' %}
        {% set locale = "se" %}    
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a variation of Dj Dac's answer.  I replace each route with two routes like this:

```
Route(r'/page', views.PageHandler),
Route(r'/<locale:\w\w>/page', views.PageHandler),
```

The route without the locale gives the default and is also used for the x-default hreflang tag.